# PIVOT the following table in sql

Tags: sql

COnvert the followig table

```
ID  Name    Category    From Date   To Date
1   A         X         1/20/2018   2/20/2018
2   A         Y         3/20/2018   4/20/2018
3   B         X         5/20/2018   6/20/2018
4   B         Y         7/20/2018   8/20/2018
```

to

```
ID  Name   X From Date  X To Date   Y From Date Y To Date
1   A      1/20/2018    2/20/2018   3/20/2018   4/20/2018
2   B      5/20/2018    6/20/2018   7/20/2018   8/20/2018
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a simple `join`:

```
select row_number() over (order by name) as id,
       name,
       tx.fromdate as x_fromdate, tx.todate as x_todate,
       ty.fromdate as y_fromdate, ty.todate as y_todate
from t tx join
     t ty
     on tx.name = ty.name and tx.category = 'x' and ty.category = 'y';
```

Comment: Please share your diet plan here as well so that others can follow and can become another Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select row_number() over (order by name) as id, name,
       max(case when cat = 'X' then fromdate end),
       max(case when cat = 'X' then todate end),
       max(case when cat = 'Y' then fromdate end),
       max(case when cat = 'Y' then todate end)
from table t
group by name;
```